# Scripting OS X GUI login window

Tags: macos, user-interface

If I open /System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow I'm able to interact with the login window by running this script:

```
osascript -e <<EOF 'tell application "System Events"
        tell process "SecurityAgent"
        set value of text field 1 of window "Login" to "password"
        click button 5 of window 1
        end tell
        end tell'
        EOF
```

I'm also able to use my script above on the real login window (/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend) when SSH'd in from another computer.

Frustratingly, however, I cannot get it to work on the real login window when run from any locally-run script.

EDIT (some context): The end goal is to have a script that runs at startup which unlocks OS X after some criteria are met (changes to a log file, etc.). In this case, I don't care about security. The hangup is being able to enter the password and "return" key to the lock screen/login window from a script, i.e. programatically.

Am I missing something? Let me know if there's other info I should provide.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The end goal is to have a script that runs at startup which unlocks OS X after some criteria are met (changes to a log file, etc.). In this case, I don't care about security. The hangup is being able to enter the password and "return" key to the lock screen/login window from a script, i.e. programatically.